# When running containers, the server cannot connect to the database

Tags: python, database, docker

I've got an issue where my Fastapi app image can't connect to a database that's also in a container
But if you turn on the database and run the application not through docker, then everything works and the connection to the database is established
[image: Here is docker]

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/"
ENV PORT=8000

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt

COPY ./app /app

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

This is my docker-compose

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - database


  database:
    image: postgres:12
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

This is error, that I'm getting

```
...
2023-03-20 11:52:17 sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused
2023-03-20 11:52:17     Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
2023-03-20 11:52:17     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2023-03-20 11:52:17 could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
2023-03-20 11:52:17     Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
2023-03-20 11:52:17     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2023-03-20 11:52:17 
2023-03-20 11:52:17 (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database is not running on `localhost` in your container, it's running in a separate container, which will be available on the hostname `database` (same as the docker compose service name). So you should change your connection string from `postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/dbname` to `postgresql://user:pass@database:5432/dbname`.